# Remove blur effect - ObjC

Tags: ios, uivisualeffectview

I'm adding blur effectt to my view like this:

```
UIBlurEffect *blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleDark];
UIVisualEffectView *blurEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];
[blurEffectView setFrame:self.view.bounds];
[self.view addSubview:blurEffectView];
```

But how can I disable/remove the blur?

Comment: If you don't want blur, why add a blur view?

Comment: I want blur in one point...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `UIVisualEffectView` subclasses `UIView`, just as you added the visual effect view to `self.view` as a subview simply hide it (the `UIView` hidden property) or remove it from the subviews.

In your case, I would add a instance variable which references the `blurEffectView` in the view, so that you can just set its hidden property to true or false if need be.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a case where the `blurView` has `subViews` (like in my case) and based on some conditions `blurEffect` would have to be enabled/disabled.

In this case, you cannot hide the `blurView` since it's `subViews` will also be hidden.

**Solution:** Set a background color (as per your expected screen background)  of the blurView with alpha 1. This gives the effect of removing the BlurEffect.

```
blurView.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(colorLiteralRed: 0.960, green: 0.960, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
```